# The math behind minimum controller sample rate compared to actual error frequency spectrum

Tags: control, pid

It seems intuitive to me that, in a digital system, a system sampling the error rate "too slowly" will fail to stabilize the system.

Is there a theory/set of metrics/equation I can use to represent this in the frequency or time domain?

i.e.

$$
e(t) : \text{Actual error (not sampled error) with respect to time}
\\
e(s) : \text{Laplace or frequency domain representation of error signal}
\\
F_s : \text{Rate at which error is sampled}
$$

If $e(t)$ has frequency components much higher than $F_s$ (or maybe if $F_s < 2\text{max}[e(s)]$ ), is it possible to properly control the system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not filter out (or filter down) the high frequency components of $e(t)$, they will be "folded back" into the desired spectrum through the process of ["aliasing"](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/22901/the-math-behind-minimum-controller-sample-rate-compared-to-actual-error-frequenc).

Practically speaking, no low-pass filter is ideal, so there will always be high frequency components that get under-sampled and aliased back.  You can view these undesired components as a noise contribution at the output of your sampler.  Depending on the nature of the high-frequency components, they might just introduce white noise that produces small random errors, or they may introduce a bias that you need to account for.

[This paper by Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa594a/slaa594a.pdf) gives a pretty comprehensive treatment of the subject.

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort. What I'm actually interested in is how sampling rate improves controller stability and behavior even with a proper anti-aliasing filter.